# .net MVC2 jQuery can't invoke action from controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, controller, invoke

Hi
I'm new to MVC and jQuery, I've followed examples which I've found in net but I have stuck
I have img element on my page to which I'm trying to add via jQuery click event and then invoke action from my controller.

**My Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="aboutContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>About</h2>
<p>
    Put content here.
</p>
<img id="img1" alt="some image" src="http://www.google.pl/logos/2010/stevenson10-hp.jpg" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $("#img1").click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/CheckAge",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("ok");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus+" - "+errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });       
</script>
```

event is added, but when I click on image I always end up on error function
and alert says **"error - undefined"**

**my controller look like this**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public static string Test()
    {
        string name = "aaa";
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CheckAge(String code)
    {
        return Json("abc");
    }
}
```

I've tried many combinations and many examples but result is allways the same 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong??
I'm Using visual web developer 2010 express

Thx for your advice

Answer (score 3):

Your CheckAge method takes a parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckAge(String code)
{
    return Json("abc");
}
```

But you aren't passing a parameter in the AJAX:

```
data: "{}",
```

You also need to wrap your script code in a `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#img1").click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/CheckAge",
            data: {code: "theCode"},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("ok");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus+" - "+errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `contentType = application/json` as request but there's nothing on the controller to understand this. The default model binder works only with standard query string parameters (`application/form-url-encoded`). So you could try this:

```
$('#img1').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<%= Url.Action("CheckAge") %>',
        data: { code: 'some code you want to send' },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.result);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus+" - "+errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

And the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckAge(string code)
{
    return Json(new { result = "abc" });
}
```

Notice how the contentType is no longer used, the data hash contains the code parameter which will be sent to the controller action and the url is no longer hardcoded but url helper is used to calculate it. Also the controller action returns JSON using an anonymous object.